# How to convert encrypted wallet.dat to decrypted? (Yes, I know the password)

Tags: wallet

I don't want to spend transaction fee for transferring coins to unencrypted wallet.dat.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you using the Bitcoin Core client,  or something else?

Comment: I use bitcoin-qt-0.8.5.ebuild and it's integrated console in debug window

Comment: Seems like there should be an easier way to do this than what Mark S proposed. Maybe it's on the core dev's to-do list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to export your private keys using the dumpprivkey functionality.

> DumpPrivKey: returns the wallet-import-format (WIP) private key corresponding to an address. (But does not remove it from the wallet.) [Bitcoin Developer Reference](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference)

Do this for each address that is storing bitcoin (use listreceivedbyaddress to view all addresses with funds)

> ListReceivedByAddress: lists the total number of bitcoins received by each address. [Bitcoin Developer Reference](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference)

Then create a backup copy of your wallet.dat file and then remove it.  The next time bitcoin-qt runs it will create a new empty unencrypted wallet.  Now you can use importprivkey to restore your funds.

> ImportPrivKey: adds a private key to your wallet. The key should be formatted in the wallet import format created by the dumpprivkey RPC. [Bitcoin Developer Reference](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference)

Comment: I don't understood, how to "Do dumpprivkey on each address that is storing coins"

Comment: I edited my answer to include information about listreceivedbyaddress which will list all of your addresses that currently hold funds

Comment: It won't list change addresses, though, will it? Be careful you don't lose those, probably should make sure to keep that back up in case.

Comment: listreceivedbyaddress shows all received coins. But I need only unspent (remaining) coins. I found <b>listunspent</b> command

Comment: And before printing keys, the wallet should be unlocked with [b]walletpassphrase[/b] command

Comment: Wouldn't dumpwallet be faster? `dumpwallet "filename" -- Dumps all wallet keys in a human-readable format.`

Answer (score -1):

You can make a paper wallet from actual addresses, then delete wallet.dat, create new one and import paper wallets on created unencypted wallet.dat file.

But you must to remember about the "change address" mechanism because you can lose your bitcoins forever.

Comment: What do you mean by "rest mechanism?"

Comment: This doesn't seem directly useful to the OP since bitcoin-qt doesn't provide the ability to either create or import paper wallets.  Perhaps you should explain in detail how to achieve these steps.

Comment: rest mechanism I mean "change address" mechanism - sorry I am not english native speaker

Comment: Nate - it is enought to have installed QR code software and use your brain a little bit (ctrl+c ctrl+v) to have this ability in bitcoin-qt also.